# How can I instantly detect browser tab close and tab reload during an webrtc call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, kurento

I have a calling system using **node.js** & **socket.io** with kurento server where users can reload their page during the call but when an user closes their tab i want to terminate the call instantly.

I'm searching the whole internet for a perfect solution but nothing is accurate as far as I have seen. I have implemented a timer based solution that is, if someone closes tab then after a particular time (30 seconds) the call is terminated, but in case of reload they join again before that particular time and therefore that timer is canceled.

But that is not an optimal solution, how can i check instantly whether an user reloaded or closed their tab?

The main problem arises when an user initiates a call and closes tab before others answer the call, in that case the call is still ringing although the initiator closed the tab, others get a feedback after the specified time of 30 seconds and it's causing issues in the system.

Comment: Handle `onbeforeunload` and get confirmation from user whether to end call or not and proceed. Would be applicable for both reload and tab close (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload)

Comment: Yes, I also tried that idea. The problem is, when tapped multiple times, a checkbox appears that says : prevent this page from creating additional dialog. If user checks this then this dialog never show again..